# Data sharing between controllers in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Hi I am new to Angularjs. I am learning how to share data between two controllers using dataservice. Looking at the tutorial I made my own program but it is not working. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Services</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="dataServiceApp">
            <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
                    <h2>First controller</h2>
                    <button>+</button>{{Holder.value}}
                  </div>
                  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl2">
                    <h2>Second controller</h2>
                    <button>+</button>{{Holder.value}}
                  </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myapp = angular.module("dataServiceApp",[]);
        myapp.factory('Holder', function() {
  return {
    value: 0
  };
});
myapp.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, Holder) {
  $scope.Holder = Holder;
  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.Holder.value++;
  };
});

myapp.controller('ChildCtrl2', function($scope, Holder) {
  $scope.Holder = Holder;
  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.Holder.value++;
  };
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by not using the version 1.4.0-beta.5. Use the latest stable version. Then tell precisely what you expect to happen and what happens instead. "not working" is much too vague. Why are you even bothering with learning AngularJS, which is dead? Why don't you learn Angular instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to register onclick listeners to the buttons:

```
<button ng-click="increment()">+</button>{{Holder.value}}
```

Hope this helps. Complete working example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Services</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="dataServiceApp">
            <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
                    <h2>First controller</h2>
                    <button ng-click="increment()">+</button>{{Holder.value}}
                  </div>
                  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl2">
                    <h2>Second controller</h2>
                    <button ng-click="increment()">+</button>{{Holder.value}}
                  </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myapp = angular.module("dataServiceApp",[]);
        myapp.factory('Holder', function() {
  return {
    value: 0
  };
});
myapp.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, Holder) {
  $scope.Holder = Holder;
  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.Holder.value++;
  };
});

myapp.controller('ChildCtrl2', function($scope, Holder) {
  $scope.Holder = Holder;
  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.Holder.value++;
  };
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

p.s. I also fully agree with JB Nizet's comment: check whether you really need to learn AngularJS instead of Angular 2-7/VueJS/React.